# Insert random number into URL when user clicks on button and hyperlink to go to another page

Tags: javascript, php, hyperlink

I have a time sheet project where employees clock in and clock out. If it is after 4pm, they have to submit a duty log before the clock out button appears.

The project is complete and functions like it should, but I found some flaws in which the employee can bypass having to fill-out the duty log by actually completing it one time and saving the URL of the duty log submission page.

Also the user can even save the clock out URL so they won't have to fill out their duty log (they can just enter the clock out URL when asked to fill it out). I want to prevent employees from doing this by **having a random number inserted to a url so when the user clicks the URL or hyperlink, the URL contains a random number each time.**

I tried both of these but it didn't work. Am I on the right track? Ideas and suggestions appreciated. If you can, can you please post an example? Thanks in advance.

### Hyperlink:

```
var url = "http://www.mypage.com/index.php?"+Math.random()

<a href="http://www.mypage.com/index.php?1" onClick="this.href=this.href.split('?')[0]+'?'+new Date().getTime()">Mostly random</a>
```

### Button:

```
echo "<form action='ClockOut.php'+Math.random() method='post'>
            <span style=\"background-color: #FFFF00\">**Please Clock Out when your shift ends**</span>
            <input value='Clock Out' id='Submit2' type='submit' /></td>               
            </form>";
```

Comment: Use a server-side solution rather than a client-side. JS can be disabled.

Comment: use mt_rand() for your random number

Comment: `mt_rand()` as noted above, `uniqid()` there are many many ways of doing this; countless actually.

Comment: as@Fred-ii- suggested dont use js if you want people to stop overriding your security checks use server side scripting

Comment: Would I just change my Math.random() to mt_rand()? I'm a noob at this and I haven't heard of mt_rand(). Can somebody please post an example thanks.

Comment: That's not quite how it works. That (PHP) function is not meant to be simply injected as a JS function. Have a look at this Q&A on Stack http://stackoverflow.com/q/22851810/ and the answer I helped with http://stackoverflow.com/a/22851863/ on the same page.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I just ran that example a few minutes ago. So are you saying that it is impossible to add random generated characters into a URL? For example, I click on that "Click Me" button in the example and I set it to a different page when clicked, would it be possible to include the random characters into the URL of a second page page?

Comment: I didn't say it was impossible to do add a random number to a URL, I meant that you can't replace `+Math.random()` for `+Math.mt_rand()` - `mt_rand()` is a PHP function and not a JS one.

Comment: Okay. Sorry for misunderstanding you.

Comment: You can do `<a href="index.php?1<?php echo uniqid();?>">Random link</a>` while using the PHP [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) function. The tacked-on `1` is just an example based on your existing `href`.

Comment: `<a href="index.php?<?php echo time() . "-" . uniqid();?>">Random link using UNIX TIMESTAMP and UNIQID()</a>` - You can't get anything more random than this; you can but it would be next to redundant. HTML source: `<a href="?index.php1407444570-53e3e65a8011b">Random link with UNIX TIMESTAMP and UNIQID()</a>`

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of doing this using a server-side PHP method, yet here is one example:

```
<a href="timekeeper.php?var<?php echo uniqid() . date('_m_d_Y_h_i_s_a', time());?>">Log time</a>
```

Which will produce something like this when clicking on the link:

`http://www.example.com/timekeeper.php?var53e4137591352_08_07_2014_08_01_57_pm`

**The breakdown:**

`?var` being taken from an `isset($_GET)`

```
if(isset($_GET["var"])) {

    echo "SUCCESS";

}
```

then,

- `53e4137591352` generated by `uniqid()` which will change each time and is unique.
- `_08_07_2014_08_01_57_pm` generated by `time()` changes also.

  - You can use UNIX TIMESTAMP also.

Functions used:

- [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)
- [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)
- [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)

So, you could replace `uniqid()` with the employee's ID number if needed (*for example*), as well as tack on any other additional random-based or time functions, just as long as they are properly formatted and concatenated.

*I hope this helps.*

Answer (score 1):

Fred -ii- is right. It is better to use Server-side solution(PHP in this case) as JS can be disabled. 
Within a few minutes I was able to find solutions for both cases. Wonder if you have made any research.

**SOLUTION 1(PHP):**

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
$characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$randomString = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
}
return $randomString;
}
```

**SOLUTION 2(JS):**

```
  function makeid()
 {
  var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

  for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ )
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

  return text;
}
```